# Why Doesn't FDT Take Into Account My Selected 'Default' SDK When I Create A Project

Tags: fdt

Check out the screenshots. I have Flex 4.6 selected as default but the project template uses Apache Flex 4.8.

Why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The project template is set to look for the highest, acceptable SDK.

To change this, go to your FDT preference folder in your home folder and change the value of the template (description.xml) from "_highest" to "_selected".

[image]

The the description.xml change:

```
<variable name="selectedSDK" label="Default SDK" default="_highest" type="sdk(3.6,4.9,1.5,4)" />
```

to:

```
<variable name="selectedSDK" label="Default SDK" default="_selected" type="sdk(3.6,4.9,1.5,4)" />
```

The [FDT wiki](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Project_Template_Syntax) has more info on using project templates.